# how to use return $.post - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'function().then')

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, post, return

I'd like to return some data from a PHP file using `$.post()`. The `$.post`-method is inside an if statement, so it does not return every time the function gets called. Here is the code for better understanding:

```
function abc() {
    ...
    ...

    function def() {
      if (a === 1) {
          // if a equals 1 it works as expected
          return $.post('file.php', formData, function(result) {}); 
      } else {
          // return $.post(); // returns whole page
    }

    def().then(function(result) { // this should be fired too if nothing returns
        console.log(result);
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: jQuery uses `.done()`, not a Promise's `.then()`.

Comment: @ChrisG not quite, `then()` works too. https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: I see, disregard my first comment then. @OP: what is returned if `a !== 1`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The problem here is that I don't want to make always a request. First I wan't to check if all input fields are filled out with JS, if yes send the data to php to check again. `def().then(function(result)` sets just red border to the input fields. But I need this no matter if a is 1 or not. Because the php file returns the names of input fields which are not filled out correctly.

Comment: I added an answer for you

Comment: @ChrisG this works of course. But I need it no matter if a is 1 or not.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you very much for your answer. Using `$.when(null)` works. Are there other options too, like `$.post(null)`? Or what exactly is the difference between `$.post` and `$.when`? Can I achieve the same with something like this: $.def().resolve().promise()?

Comment: The difference is that `$.post` returns a jqXHR object, while `$.when` returns a `promise`. I'm not sure of exactly what jQuery does internally, but when you provide `null` to `$.when` it gives you an empty promise which is already resolved, allowing you to chain the then/done etc methods from it

Comment: In fact I checked the [source](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=jQuery.when). You can see that when there is no `subordinate` argument `deferred.resolveWith()` is called, which resolves the promise before it's returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to address this. Firstly you could amend your logic so that the `def()` function always makes the AJAX request. You then just need to move the `if` condition outside of it:

```js
function abc() {
  // some code...

  function def() {
    return $.post('file.php', formData, function(result) {});
  }

  if (a === 1) {
    def().then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      // some code...
    });
  }
}
```

This obviously makes the `def()` itself rather redundant.

Another approach is to return an empty, resolved promise from within the `else` condition. You can use `$.when` to do that:

```js
function abc() {
  // some code...

  function def() {
    if (a === 1) {
      return $.post('file.php', formData, function(result) {});
    } else {
      return $.when(null);
    }

    def().then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      // some code...
    });
  }
}
```